# Is there a design pattern for a measurment/value relationship?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, measurement

I've to work with a large database that contains measurement targets as well as warning/error areas for the measurement values.

```
public class Measurement<T>
{
    public T Target { get; set; }

    public float? UpperWarnLimit { get; set; }
    public float? LowerWarnLimit { get; set; }
    public float? UpperErrorLimit { get; set; }
    public float? LowerErrorLimit { get; set; }
}
```

These measurements are assigned to specifications:

```
public class Specification
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Measurement<float> Width { get; set; }
    public Measurement<float> Height { get; set; }
    public Measurement<int> AdditionalMeasurement { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

So whenever a user does a measurement, the system collects information from various database tables, assembles a specification object and collects the measurement values. In some cases the specification has to be changed:

```
 public interface IDatabase
 {
     Specification GetSpecification(long id);
     void UpdateSpecification(Specification specification)
 }
```

Everything looks good so far, but there is also a case where a user has to store the test results in the database and I'm not sure what is the best way to solve this problem.

My initial solution was to alter the measurement and database class like this:

```
public class Measurement<T>
{
    public T Target { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; } // <-- New


public interface IDatabase
{
    void StoreTestResults(Specification specification) // <-- New
```

But it doesn't feel right, because in fact the user stores a test result and not a specification. I'm looking for a better way to do this.

*To clear it up:* I want to separate the test results from the specification with the least amount of additional complexity possible.

A typical code scenario with the changes I mentioned:

```
 var s = GetSpecification(123);
 s.Height.Value = 4;
 if (s.Height.Value > s.Height.Target * s.Height.Target.UpperErrorLimit)
 {
    ...
 }
 StoreTestResults(s);
```

This is simple and pretty straight forward but there is no clear separation between the test results and the specification itself.

Comment: It might help if you described the point of this a little more, perhaps gave some concrete examples of what you are doing.

Comment: @Marcin: I added a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your design (although you have given almost no details).

I think your use of the name "specification" may have fooled you into thinking that it is for storing specifications.

If you need to separate specifications from results at the type level (and I urge you not to do so unless necessary), then create a base class with all of the common elements (which may be everything), and inherit from it for specification and result, and use a neutral name.

If you *don't* need to separate the two concepts, then choose a more neutral name than "specification" and be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not accepting it yet, because I'm obviously interested in different opinions and ideas.

Comment: @xsl I always like to wait too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overloading the `Measurement<T>` class.  You're using it to encapsulate both your limits and your test results.  You might want to split this into two separate classes.  How does this sound?

```
public class AcceptableRange<T>
{
    public T UpperWarnLimit { get; set; }
    public T LowerWarnLimit { get; set; }
    public T UpperErrorLimit { get; set; }
    public T LowerErrorLimit { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Specification
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public AcceptableRange<float> Width { get; set; }
    public AcceptableRange<float> Height { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Measurement<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Test
{
    public Specification Specification { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class TestResult
{
    public Test Test { get; set; }
    public Measurement<float> Width { get; set; }
    public Measurement<float> Height { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This allows you to separate the specification data from the test data and multiple instances of a test can refer to the same specification.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I also thought of a solution similar to the one you described here, but the problem is that I have to repeat all specification properties in the test result class. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Not if you want to have a clean separation.  The only alternative I can think of to not have hard-coded properties.  Instead populate a HashTable/Dictionary where the key is a string containing the name of the property and the object will be an AcceptableRange in the Specification and a Measurement in the TestResult.  This simplifies your code here, but you'll then need code elsewhere to populate the collections.

Comment: This introduces a lot of extra complexity. What's the benefit?

Comment: Decouples the limits in the specification from the values in the test results.  There are trade offs, and whether it's worth it is not for me to say.  That's up to the asker.